# NTFS or FAT32:Formatting Disk for PFSense

Tags: ntfs, pfsense, formatting, fat32

Im a network guy, and know very little about system administration.  I would like to install PFSense and Monowall to 2 CF Cards, but not sure how they should be formatted (NTFS or FAT32) and volume size. Both of the cards are 8 gigs.  I was also wondering if it would be a problem using physdiskwrite with -u flag for disks over 2 gig.

Comment: What's the [tag:openbsd] tag in there for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PFSense](http://pfsense.org) and [Monowall](http://m0n0.ch) are both based on [FreeBSD](http://freebsd.org) (which is not Windows, not a Microsoft product, nothing like the aforementioned, does not use their file systems) and use [UFS/FFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System) as their primary file system.

You should let their installers slice and format the "disks". The `physdiskwrite` utility can write an image file to the cards, you have to override the safety mechanism with `-u` as Chop has mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the correct answer is neither. You should probably follow the instructions for installing an embedded pfsence ( I assume the CF cards will go into some sort of headless box.)

http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Installing_pfSense#Embedded

Answer (score 4):

You *have* to use the `-u` option for disks over 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

Both use neither. When you write the CF it blows away whatever partitions you have on it. One note, with Windows Vista and 7 and physdiskwrite, you cannot have any partition on the CF that's readable by Windows or physdiskwrite fails.